# Sequence and Limits: Symbolab issue

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

From the *James Stewart Essential Calculus Early Transcendentals Second Edition* textbook I have the given problem:

> $$a_n=\frac{(-3)^n}{n!}$$

I did the following absolute convergence procedure, because I treated the problem as the following:

### Theorem 6

If $ \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\rvert a_n \lvert = 0$, $\ \therefore \ $ $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$
$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n (3)^n}{n!}$$
I then then proceeded to do the following, in accordance to the theorem, and the way which I manipulated the sequence.
\begin{align}
\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \vert \frac{(-1)^n (3)^n}{n!} \vert \\
\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{ (3)^n}{n!}
\end{align}

Here is where I get a bit lost because of the intuition behind the problem, I graphed this as function, and determined the limit equals 0, but I am trying to determine it analytically. I went to Symbolab, and it says that numerator is undefined, and that its denominator is infinity, thus it being 0. But this is how I view the problem.

### My Work

$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{ (3)^n}{n!}$$
$$\frac{3^\infty}{\infty!}$$
My thoughts were that the $3^\infty = \infty$, thus being $$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$.
Is there something I am missing, because L^Hopital's rule is not applicable here. How do I analytically get at the problem?

Comment: You definitely should not simply plug in $\infty$ and try to manipulate that, ever.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt So its not $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?

Comment: That's not useful in the slightest. You don't solve limits such as $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x/e^x$ by saying it equals $e^\infty/e^\infty=\infty/\infty$ and then going from there...

Comment: No I know you can't do anything from there that's the dead end, because I am trying to find a way to manipulate it.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt omg You are like the best, I didn't find any associated questions thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem.